# Clear the Contents of a File

Tags: c#, .net, file

How does one clear the contents of a file?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can use the [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx)  method.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"Path/foo.bar",string.Empty);
```

Comment: I have a hardlinked a file, and use `File.WriteAllText`, it seems as if this sometimes (?) deletes the file since the hardlinks are not kept updated.

Comment: I recommend you to do not do that if another operation will access the file right after this operation. I faced issue where the file didn't get closed write after this line of code, and cause `IO exceptions of file is in use`, so i recommend you to handle it manually through file stream

Answer (score 97):

This is what I did to **clear the contents of the file without creating a new file** as I didn't want the file to display new time of creation even when the application just updated its contents.

```
FileStream fileStream = File.Open(<path>, FileMode.Open);

/* 
 * Set the length of filestream to 0 and flush it to the physical file.
 *
 * Flushing the stream is important because this ensures that
 * the changes to the stream trickle down to the physical file.
 * 
 */
fileStream.SetLength(0);
fileStream.Close(); // This flushes the content, too.
```

Comment: I used .NET 3.5, just in case you want to know the version.

Comment: Olive, if it answers your question, would you please mark it as an answer. However, if the proposed solution doesn't work in your case, please let us know even then.

Comment: +1 This is the only way to first acquire a file lock, check file attributes safely and finally clear the content.

Comment: @mafutrct: It is not required. Closing a stream makes sure that the data is flushed.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed myself...i need to have a service communicate to an application for simple line-by-line messages to a user, and this allows me to keep my file lock and clear the messages to prevent the service app from inserting and inadvertently dropping messages or duplicating messages.

Comment: I'm using a Compact Framework and this solution is perfect for this environment.

Comment: Wouldn't it be advisable to create the filestream in a using block? That would automatically close the stream as well.

Answer (score 15):

Use `FileMode.Truncate` everytime you create the file. Also place the `File.Create` inside a `try` `catch`.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty)
```

However, I recommend you use `FileStream` because the first solution can throw `UnauthorizedAccessException`

```
using(FileStream fs = File.Open(path,FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
     lock(fs)
     {
          fs.SetLength(0);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using something like

[File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

> Creates or overwrites a file in the
>   specified path.

Comment: Not a good idea for the question asked: Does not remove the data already in the file - it only overwrites it to the length of the new data, so if old data > new data you will end up with mix of the two.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is perhaps deleting the file via your application and creating a new one with the same name... in even simpler way just make your application overwrite it with a new file.

Comment: There can be problems if you try to create the file shortly after deletion. Sometimes the OS fails to create file as it "thinks" the file still exists.

Comment: @Dmitry Lobanov - [I know this is an old thread]. I do not accept that the operating system sometimes thinks a file still exists, unless there is a good reason. It would be a very poor OS if it did. MUCH more likely is that something still has a handle open on the existing file. It could even be your own software if you are not careful in closing files (by using 'using' for example to ensure disposal). Could be the anti-virus too. Agree with your conclusion though. I think FileMode.Truncate is the way to go.