# Making a file empty

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

I have a csv file.

On Certain condition, I want to make the file empty.

How i can make the file empty. as i dont not delete it & create a new file.

Please suggest any.

Thanks

Comment: how are you opening and reading the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, new byte[] { 0 });
```

Will turn the CSV into a void. If you actually want a blank CSV file (as opposed to an empty file), then replace the `byte[]` parameter with the actual bytes of an empty CSV file (from a template that you've prepared from Excel, for example).

Comment: There is no reason to create a one-byte file, containing a single `zero` byte, as you are doing here. In fact this is an invalid CSV file. Neither a C-style string terminator byte (as perhaps suggested by your confusing use of the word "void")—which would indeed be zero but is never stored in a text file—nor any kind of console terminator sequence (such as `ctrl-Z`, perhaps?) are used in "on-disk" text file formats, including CSV. A terminator byte isn't needed because the file system maintains the exact length of every file in separate "directory entry" metadata for each file.

Answer (score 5):

How about `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath,string.Empty);`

Found here: [To clear the contents of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999988/to-clear-the-contents-of-a-file)

Answer (score 3):

Use the FileMode.Truncate mode to set the files size to zero:

```
(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Truncate)).Close()
```

Comment: Nice, but you're not disposing the `FileStream`. I think `(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Truncate)).Dispose();` might be better. Note that standard `Dispose()` implementations are always supposed to call `Close()`—but definitely not the other way around!